# C++ TCHAR array to wstring not working in VS2010

Tags: c++, arrays, wstring, tchar

I would like to convert a TCHAR array to a wstring.

```
    TCHAR szFileName[MAX_PATH+1];
#ifdef _DEBUG
    std::string str="m:\\compiled\\data.dat";
    TCHAR *param=new TCHAR[str.size()+1];
    szFileName[str.size()]=0;
    std::copy(str.begin(),str.end(),szFileName);
#else
    //Retrieve the path to the data.dat in the same dir as our data.dll is located
    GetModuleFileName(_Module.m_hInst, szFileName, MAX_PATH+1);
    StrCpy(PathFindFileName(szFileName), _T("data.dat"));
#endif  

wstring sPath(T2W(szFileName));
```

I need to pass `szFileName` to a function that expects

```
const WCHAR *
```

For completeness I am stating the void that I need to pass `szFileName` to:

```
HRESULT CEngObj::MapFile( const WCHAR * pszTokenVal,  // Value that contains file path
                        HANDLE * phMapping,          // Pointer to file mapping handle
                        void ** ppvData )            // Pointer to the data
```

However, T2W does not work for me. The compiler says `that "_lpa" is not defined`, and I don't know where to go on from here. I have tried other conversion methods that I found stated on the net, but they did not work either.

Comment: The fundamental rule while using `TCHAR` is that, use tchar functions and similar routines always. `std::copy` isn't really a right way to convert between a `TCHAR` and `std::string`. One of the simplest way to express `LPCTSTR szFileName = _T("m:\\compiled\\data.dat");` You don't need that complex copying code. If want unicode variant `LPCWSTR szFileName = L"m:\\compiled\\data.dat"`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are functions like

```
mbstowcs_s()
```

that convert from `char*` to `wchar_t*`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

char *orig = "Hello, World!";
cout << orig << " (char *)" << endl;

// Convert to a wchar_t*
size_t origsize = strlen(orig) + 1;
const size_t newsize = 100;
size_t convertedChars = 0;
wchar_t wcstring[newsize];
mbstowcs_s(&convertedChars, wcstring, origsize, orig, _TRUNCATE);
wcscat_s(wcstring, L" (wchar_t *)");
wcout << wcstring << endl;
```

Look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76252/What-are-TCHAR-WCHAR-LPSTR-LPWSTR-LPCTSTR-etc) for an article and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235631%28VS.80%29.aspx) for MSDN.

Comment: `TCHAR` is defined automatically by the system header files. There is no need to do it yourself.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg don't know where I read it, but seemed vital there

Comment: I found the solution somewhere: USES_CONVERSION; Can anybody tell me what this does?

Comment: It is a [macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The definition of `TCHAR` differs depending on if certain preprocessor macros are defined or not. See e.g. [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c426s321%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for the possible combinations.

This means that `TCHAR` may already be a `wchar_t`.

You can use the `_UNICODE` macro to check if you need to convert the string. If you do, then you can use [`mbstowcs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1f9b8cy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to do the conversion:

```
std::wstring str;

#ifdef _UNICODE
    // No need to convert the string
    str = your_tchar_string;
#else
    // Need to convert the string
    // First get the length needed
    int length = mbstowcs(nullptr, your_tchar_string, 0);

    // Allocate a temporary string
    wchar_t* tmpstr = new wchar_t[length + 1];

    // Do the actual conversion
    mbstowcs(tmpstr, your_tchar_str, length + 1);

    str = tmpstr;

    // Free the temporary string
    delete[] tmpstr;
#endif
```